# this.name is undefined in my Mongoose schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm having a problem. In my kittySchema Mongoose schema. Line 21. I'm trying to get this.name from within the schema object but I'm getting undefined.
I know what the problem is. I'm using an arrow function and It's looking for the this.name property in the arrow function instead of the object that the arrow function is in. Is there a way around this instead of me using a regular vanilla js function?
`

```
// Requiring Mongoose
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const establishConnection = () => {
    // Establishing a connection to Mongoose
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/kittens");

    // Getting the Mongoose database from the pending connection
    const db = mongoose.connection;

    // Watching for Mongoose errors
    db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "Connection error:"))
    // A connection was succesfully established
    db.once("open", () => {
        console.log("A connection was established");
        const kittySchema = mongoose.Schema({
            name: String
        });`enter code here`
        mongoose.
        kittySchema.methods.speak = () => {
            console.log(this.name ? `Meow, My name is ${this.name}.` : "I don't have a name.");
        }
        const Kitten = mongoose.model("Kitten", kittySchema);
        const silence = new Kitten({ name: "Silence" });
        console.log(`A new kitty named ${silence.name} was successfully added to your database!`);
        silence.speak();
    })
}

module.exports = {
    establishConnection
}
```

`

Comment: What happenes when you make the 'speak' method in to a normal function? (ie - `kittySchema.methods.speak = function () { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you already know, Arrow function does not have a `this` itself, so you already got the problem, what you can do, is to wrap your arrow function within a regular function :

```
var myKitty = {
  name: "Majid",
  kittyMethod : function() { 
    return (() => {
        console.log(this.name ? `Meow, My name is ${this.name}.` : "I don't have a name.");
    })();
}
}
myKitty.kittyMethod ();//Mew, My Name is Majid
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a2ww7tby/

Comment: Ty. I'll give it try.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using an arrow function and It's looking for the this.name
>   property in the arrow function instead of the object that the arrow
>   function is in

This assumption is slightly wrong. The arrow function looks for the value in the lexical scope. In this case, it happens to be `global` object.

On the other hand, if you used a 'regular' function, the 'this' would be bound to the new object that is created when you instantiate the new Kitten.

To fix your issue, simply use a regular function in place of the arrow function.

```
kittySchema.methods.speak = function() {
    console.log(this.name ? `Meow, My name is ${this.name}.` : "I don't have a name.");
}
```

There is no need to wrap the arrow function.

You can read more about when not to use arrow functions [here](https://dmitripavlutin.com/when-not-to-use-arrow-functions-in-javascript/).